# os.system not working with init.d script

Tags: python-2.7, os.system

I am new to python and hence forgive me if I am doing something stupid here. I am trying to get a piece of shell script working from my python code which is executing on the instance boot up(part of the init.d script).

```
try:
   os.system("sudo mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 $(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone).fs-e103e928.efs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:/ /staticshopcontent")
except:
    sys.exit("Unable to mount EFS for staticshop")
```

The code works when I run the python script manually but isn't mounting the EFS directory on bootup.

Comment: Make sure you do " import sys " with out the quotes at the top of the script.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...yes I am doing that.....it works when I run it manually but isn't when it is being run by the init.d module.

Answer (score 0):

since your using Linux you might as well as not even use python a much simpler solution would be just to use bash.

put this in a file called script.txt or what ever.

then do

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 $(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone).fs-e103e928.efs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:/ /staticshopcontent
```

Save that to the txt file then login as root and create a chron tab.
do

```
crontab script.txt @reboot
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am actually using the python to use a list of other tasks too and hence to keep things simple wanted to use this approach.